# Server CPU Usage Above 100% for the Past Week

Tags: ubuntu, postfix, python, apache2, flask

My server running ubuntu and flask for a webapp as well as scrapy, selenium, and postfix has been experiencing very abnormal cpu usage. This server has not used as much cpu load in the past, but has recently increased by a very large amount. Any help would be very much appreciated to reduce the server load! Thanks!

[IMAGE1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3subc.png)
[IMAGE2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ootKO.png)

Comment: There is not enough information to diagnose this, but a fair bet is that it's not your server anymore; someone infected it with malware. In that case: nuke and rebuild.

Comment: Show ‘top’ output. Don’t link is an image but include as a text.

Comment: I have weekly backups of the server should I restore from one of those?